# what is the value of height in case image width, image border width is mentioned without mentioning height

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and CSS, have setup `img` element's **width** and **border width** with style element.

But I'm not understanding in this case how is the `height` gets calculated ?  I've looked in W3School documentation but couldn't find clear answer

Comment: the image has an intrinsic ratio so the height will be calculated to keep that ratio based on the width you specify

Answer (score 0):

an image is a replaced inline element and for sure have an intrinsic ratio so the following rule apply:

> Otherwise, if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element has an intrinsic ratio then the used value of 'height' is:
>
> (used width) / (intrinsic ratio)

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced